# Is there any way to get Windows Environment Variables value in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm setting up my configuration for laravel project, which usually could use **.env (dotEnv)**. 
But as for the project requirements, project manager requires us the development team (programmer) may not know the **database password** which usually placed in .env file.

The project running under Windows Server 2016 OS. 
I thought that it may viable to store database password in **System Environment Variables** as we Development team does not have access to open Environment Variables due to restricted access

Expected to get database password stored in System Environment Variables

Comment: [Environment variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.environment.php)

Comment: Or you can look into [`getenv()`](https://www.php.net/getenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the global variable `$_ENV` or the method `getenv('variable')`.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks! used getenv() and it successfully obtain the value.
Well, I have to restart my computer after adding the value though
Thanks for help anyway... :)